# when use nested destructuring assignment and default value typescript threw errors

Tags: typescript

```js
interface TaskListItemType {
  id: number;
}
type PageType =  {
  current?: number;
  size?: number;
  total?: number;
}
declare const data:{
    records: TaskListItemType[];
    page: PageType;
} | undefined
 const { records, page: { total, current, size } = {} } = data|| {};
```

[play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.5#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQBUEGcDWAZELCASWgFt0BPABzQG9hVUQATALlTAFcyAjWANzAAvsAg00ABQQBzKFVqoAvEwZMkXGDCiQA-B259BjVFhAAvKPs49+MIUwgB7CAgA21w3aGiWUJG4I2qhITmBEqCwIrmxqTKjaoTAsWByYuAREpFAUEgDaALoO8dSyUBzScgpQPqgAPqhcYH5w4FAsjKHhEKh0Cf5OyVgANKilchx9zq5uoxpaOhCjZpaowsq96+sqUa51DXTCQsBAA)

It will throw `Initializer provides no value for this binding element and the binding element has no default value`.

I thought the reason is the `{}` doesn't have these  properties. So I added an assert. It works.

```js
const { records, page: { total, current, size } = {} as PageType } = data|| {};
```

But if the reason is the `{}` doesn't have these  properties. Why doesn't the code below throw errors

```
interface TaskListItemType {
  id: number;
}
type PageType =  {
  current?: number;
  size?: number;
  total?: number;
}
declare const data:{
    records: TaskListItemType[];
    page: PageType;
} | undefined

const { records, page } = data|| {};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is related to the optionality of the fields within the `PageType` type

If we assess:

```
type PageType = {
  current?: number;
  size?: number;
  total?: number;
}
```

We can see that all fields are optional. In other words, this is a completely valid `PageType`:

```
{}
```

Observe that your `data` type has a property `page` which is not optional/nullable and is always of type `PageType`. If this type definition is accurate, you do not need to provide a fallback object for the `page` property because it will never be falsy (an empty object `{}` is still truthy). In other words, this:

```
const {
  records,
  page: {
    total,
    current,
    size
  } = {}
} = data || {};
```

can simply be rewritten as this:

```
const {
  records,
  page: {
    total,
    current,
    size
  }
} = data || {};
```

`current`, `size` and `total` will be destructured to a number if present, or `undefined` if not

[TypeScript Playground #1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.5#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQBUEGcDWAZELCASWgFt0BPABzQG9hVUQATALlTAFcyAjWANzAAvsAg00ABQQBzKFVqoAvKgZMkXGDCiQA-B259BjVFhAAvKPs49%20MIUwgB7CAgA21w3aGiWUJG4I2qhITmBEqCwIrmxqTKjaoTAsWByYuAREpFAUEgDaALoO8dSyUBzScgpQPsCh4RCqCf5OyVgANKilchx0qM6ubp0aWjoQnWaWqMLTypHRCKgAPkuqwkLAQA)

---

However to answer your actual question, TypeScript evaluates this as a valid assignment to a variable that **may have** contained the keys `current`, `size` or `total`

```
const typedEmptyObject: PageType = {}
```

whereas this

```
const untypedEmptyObject = {}

// aka
const untypedEmptyObject: {} = {}
```

Is an object that is not expected to have any specific properties, including `current`, `size` or `total`

Destructuring `typedEmptyObject` to return `current`, `size` or `total` is safe by the TS compiler, as by assigning `PageType` to that variable, we are stating that any variable of this type **may** have had those properties. The TS compiler has no indication that `untypedEmptyObject` should have ever had any of those properties and will therefore complain.

```
const typedEmptyObject: PageType = {};
const untypedEmptyObject: {} = {};

const {
  records,
  page: {
    total,
    current,
    size
  } = typedEmptyObject // valid
} = data || {};

const {
  records,
  page: {
    total,
    current,
    size
  } = untypedEmptyObject // invalid
} = data || {};
```

[TypeScript Playground #2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.5#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQBUEGcDWAZELCASWgFt0BPABzQG9hVUQATALlTAFcyAjWANzAAvsAg00ABQQBzKFVqoAvKgZMkXGDCiQA-B259BjVFhAAvKPs49%20MIUwgB7CAgA21w3aGiWUJG4I2qhITmBEqCwIrmxqTKjaoTAsWByYuAREpFAUEgDaALoO8dSyUBzScgpQPsDAoeEQqOK0LACiZNTiAPK8AFb%20EBVl1cqqwkINEVyQEu2dPf2DHHTCY6tC9WERcYlOyVgANCalcismji7ux-EhmtqQN-FmliZrKi1Q812UvQNITQA9IDUAA3dysERjKKuVAAHzh402wJC2yaDBRTD2B2OmNQp3KqmAeMurjcuJBtw0Wh0EApt1MFigxMpqHeqBmn2%20i3%20QJB4HBbkhKPZMIQ8MRGzqQA)

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your answer, That very wonderful. And it inspired me.

But there are also some problems.

1. If i delete the fallback for `page`. It won' work, Because the `data` may be `undefined`.

2.

In your explain. I thing the reason probably is like  this.

`const page= {} ; const { total } = page `

But the problem is why is the `data`'s default value working.

It also has a default value `|| {}`.

Comment: And here are some additional thoughts. please correct me.

1. in fact. if I provide a  default value `const defaultData = {records:[], page:{}}` to data, It will throw a different error.
2. I think it might be better if typescript could check `|| {}`.